# Simple form and page curl for automatic email

Tags: php, forms, curl

I'm still trying to wrap my head around a few things. Right now I've got what I want, but I'd like to add one more aspect. I've got my newsletter form and it sends me and email on sign up. I'd like to know at what page this was done. Here is the code in its entirety .

```
   <?php
$name = "";
$email = "";
$msg_to_user = "";
if ($_POST['name'] != "") {

    include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";

    // Be sure to filter this data to deter SQL injection, filter before querying database
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_POST['name'])));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_POST['email'])));

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE email='$email'");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

    if (!$email) {

        $msg_to_user = '<div class="warning"><ul><li>Please type an email address ' . $name . '.</li></ul></div><br /><br />';

    } else if ($numRows > 0) {

        $msg_to_user = '<div class="warning"><ul><li>' . $email . ' is already in the system.</li></ul></div><br /><br />';

    } else {

        $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (name, email, dateTime) 
                                                    VALUES('$name','$email',now() )")  or die (mysql_error());

        $msg_to_user = '<div class="success"><ul><li>Thanks ' . $name . ', hope you find what you want!</li></ul></div><br /><br />';
        $name = "";
        $email = "";
    }
    $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . 'Page:'.$curPageURL.', Email: ' . $_POST['email']; 
mail('newproducts@.com', 'New Newsletter Sign Up at Jewelry',  $message);
}
?>
```

and this is the portion I'm having the issue with.

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
```

Notice that I'm trying to include that in the email that is sent to me that lets me know I'm getting a sign up for a newsletter. Am I approaching this in the wrong way or am I on the right path? If I'm off please let me know of any solutions or tips that may be helpful.

**ADDITION OF dump

```
array(35) { ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]=> string(2) "58" ["CONTENT_TYPE"]=> string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(27) "/home3/onlinfr7/public_html" ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" ["HTTPS"]=> string(2) "on" ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(63) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(13) "gzip, deflate" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.5" ["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=> string(9) "max-age=0" ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=> string(197) "PHPSESSID=05ii2k0b7preeuc01jno24cfe1; __utma=160231841.1736281531.1369590827.1369876044.1369888331.9; __utmc=160231841; __utmz=160231841.1369590827.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)" ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(30) "www.moniquetrinidadjewelry.com" ["HTTP_REFERER"]=> string(61) "https://www.moniquetrinidadjewelry.com/bracelet/bracelets.php" ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(72) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" ["PATH"]=> string(13) "/bin:/usr/bin" ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=> string(3) "200" ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(13) "72.191.32.243" ["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "64668" ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(4) "POST" ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(23) "/bracelet/bracelets.php" ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(50) "/home3/onlinfr7/public_html/bracelet/bracelets.php" ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(23) "/bracelet/bracelets.php" ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(13) "67.20.101.172" ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(36) "webmaster@moniquetrinidadjewelry.com" ["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(30) "www.moniquetrinidadjewelry.com" ["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(3) "443" ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(76) "
Apache Server at www.moniquetrinidadjewelry.com Port 443
" ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(6) "Apache" ["SSL_TLS_SNI"]=> string(30) "www.moniquetrinidadjewelry.com" ["file_gzip"]=> string(20) "/ramdisk/cpud/status" ["PHPRC"]=> string(40) "/home3/onlinfr7/public_html/:/etc/php53/" ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(23) "/bracelet/bracelets.php" ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1369955110) }
```

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER). what do you get out?

Comment: Hi Farkie. Thanks for the quick response. Ii'm not sure where to add var_dump($_SERVER) to the script. Can you help me understand that. I'd love to know what the output is as well.

Comment: Anywhere to be honest. It's an array full of server environment variables, so it will help build the correct URL.

Comment: okay, thanks Farkie I just posted it to the original message

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Which result do you get and how is this not the desired one?

Comment: I've got it set to send name and email to my email address at sign up. The page is not displaying within the received email. thanks for your reply.